# If I turn it onto peaceful are there still zombie pigmen in the nether reactor?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am just making my last gold block for the nether reactor and it is on peaceful but I am worried that there will still be zombie pigmen there, is this true?

Comment: Go and find out. Zombie Pigmen are naturally peaceful and won't attack you unless you start attacking them.

Comment: @Alice This is PE, where the only zombie pigmen are in the Nether Reactor and they're always hostile.

Comment: Dang. Sounds pretty harsh

Answer (score 1):

No. Hostile mobs don't spawn in peaceful mode and since the mcpe zombie pigmen are hostile they don't spawn on peaceful difficulty. The items still spawn though.

Comment: will zombiepigmen still atack you in the nether reactor?

Comment: Zombie pigmen are neutral mobs. Neutral mobs don't spawn in peaceful. @user119520 No.

Answer (score 0):

No they don't, but mob spawners can still spawn but there will be no pigmen

Answer (score 0):

No. They will not spawn because just like the pc and Xbox version, if you put your game onto peaceful they will not spawn.